# Is OAuth useful when Auth and Service Provider are the same?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth

When reading about REST APIs and security, you invariably see OAuth 2.0 as the authentication panacea. But actually diving into the specs, true OAuth 2.0 requires service and authentication providers be separate, primarily so the authentication provider can be used for multiple services. Also clients are untrusted and not given credentials. OAuth seems an overly convoluted if your service and auth provider are the same.

On top of that many APIs just use some sort of client id/client secret into bearer token flow. Which is no better than username/password into session.

Answer (score 0):

You split between Auth[-Provider] and Service-Provider, but actually there are 3 pieces involved:

1. Authentication.
2. Service Provider.
3. Service Consumer.

It is very common that Authentication and Service Provider are done by the same party.

It depends on the service consumer, if you need OAuth or not. In case you want 3-rd party applications to consume your services ON BEHALF of your users, OAuth is very useful.